# Sql Installer .net : sqlinstaller.exe : Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding

Tags: sql, postgresql, windows-server-2012-r2

Brief info:

I have two servers: Win1 and Win2 (both are windows server 2012) Win2 was create from a Win1 image.

Following are the files:

[image]

I am trying to execute the SQLInstaller.exe on Win2 and getting the following error: 
"sqlinstaller : error : Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding."

However it works fine on Win1. I copied the sqlinstaller.exe and other files from Win1 to Win2 but still no luck.

I am not sure how to investigate the problem any further? Please help.

Comment: There may have been an error in copying the installer over. I would suggest trying to download a new SQLInstaller (for the same version of SQL on Win1) and try to install that on Win2.

Comment: After installing the sqlinstaller I do not get the same error when running  .exe out side of my project.  So its definitely something to do with my config/db/connection.  I'll investigate further and come back with my findings. Thank you so far.

Comment: After spending many hours I still don't have a solutions. I am also having discussion with someone at [SQLInstaller](https://sqlinstaller.codeplex.com/discussions/581132).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Remove weird looking file from here(in my case it was:
   za11yvwt.zvb): %LocalAppData%\IsolatedStorage\
2. Execute SQLInstaller.exe and it should work

Credit goes to: [bscholz](https://sqlinstaller.codeplex.com/discussions/581132#PostDetailsCell_1353280)